# Box Shadow without adding margin

Tags: css

Is it possible to add a box shadow without adding a "margin"? Basically, I have a wrapper div, and I don't want the box-shadow to create a margin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, and in fact, adding a `box-shadow` *does not* implicitly add a margin.

[A simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/uXCRw/) shows this to be true: the spacing between the `span`s is caused by the space in the source; that is not a margin, and no margin is added.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out that I didn't do a CSS reset and that fixed it.